# Using Loops to Reset Basic Financial Calculator

Tags: java, while-loop

I cannot quite figure out how to make my basic financial calculator be able to run a new set of numbers without closing the program. What I currently have allows me to run one set of numbers, and when I get to "Would you like to continue?", when I press 1 it simply will print "Would you like to continue?" however many times I press 1. Here is what I have so far:

```
package Register;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Register {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        Register myRegister = new Register();
        
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Electricity Bill calculator.");
        System.out.print("Enter amount of electricity (kW) used in the daytime: ");
        
        float num1 = scan.nextFloat();
        System.out.print("Enter amount of electricity (kW) used in the evening: ");
        float num2 = scan.nextFloat();
        
        System.out.print("Enter rate for daytime: ");
       
        float num3 = scan.nextFloat();
        System.out.print("Enter rate for evening: ");
        float num4 = scan.nextFloat();
        float day1 = num1 * num3;   
        float night2 = num2 * num4;
        float total = day1 + night2;
        
        {
            System.out.println("Electricity Bill: $" + total);
        }
        System.out.println("");
        
        boolean keepLooping = true;
        while (keepLooping) {
            System.out.print("Would you like to continue? Press 1 continue or 0 to exit.");
            int answer = scan.nextInt();
            if(answer == 0) {
                keepLooping = false;
            
            } else {
                keepLooping = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used while loop around asking choice statements only. So use while loop at the beginning in main method as below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Register{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Register myRegister = new Register();
        
        boolean keepLooping = true;
        while(keepLooping) {
        
            System.out.println("Welcome to the Electricity Bill calculator.");
            System.out.print("Enter amount of electricity (kW) used in the daytime: ");
            float num1 = scan.nextFloat();
        
            System.out.print("Enter amount of electricity (kW) used in the evening: ");
            float num2 = scan.nextFloat();
            
            System.out.print("Enter rate for daytime: ");
            float num3 = scan.nextFloat();
            
            System.out.print("Enter rate for evening: ");
            float num4 = scan.nextFloat();
            
            float day1 = num1 * num3;
            float night2 = num2 * num4;
            float total = day1 + night2;
            
            System.out.println("Electricity Bill: $" + total);
            System.out.println("");
        
            System.out.print("Would you like to continue? Press 1 continue or 0 to exit.");
            int answer = scan.nextInt();
            if(answer == 0) {
                keepLooping = false;
            
            } else {
                keepLooping = true;
            }
    
        }
    }
    
}
```